# How to exclude thumbnail refresh traffic from Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

A large portion of my Google Analytics 'traffic' appears to come from the automatic refreshment of browser thumbnails. The most obvious culprits are single-page visits to the same obscure deep pages (e.g. internal search results) reoccurring approximately daily, always using Chrome or Safari, and giving every indication via the various other measures (e.g. Browser Version, Network, Screen Res. etc.)  of being the same user / device. These readily identifiable instances account for a quarter of my total GA 'visits' but I suppose there are many more hidden amongst the home page visitors etc.

Most of the available reports are rendered virtually meaningless by the inclusion of this traffic so, 1.) is there any way I can excluded it, and 2.) is everyone else really just making do with this as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Page Visibility api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) to determine whether a page is being rendered as a preview (a 'prerender') or whether the page is a true pageview, in which case the visibilitystate will be set to 'visible'.

[This tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/) shows how you can use the page visibility api to disable google analytics tracking unless the page is visible.

Also you should note that google analytics automatically excludes prerenders from Chrome. I can't find a good reference for this but if you have a look at the ga sources 
and search for "webkitvisibilitychange" you will get a match.

Comment: Page Visibility API did the trick, thanks. My traffic figures have now plummeted. Result!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't really a reliable way to separate regular page views and thumbnail "previews" or similar (e.g. google also has the site preview feature on their SERP which also renders your page).

One thing I have tried was to set a cookie with the url. The cookie is updated on every page view with the current url. Then I have some code to check if the cookie value is the same as the current url. Then I also check to see if `document.referrer` has a value.  If the cookie value is the same as the current url and there is no `document.referrer`, I do not pop the tracking code.

Also, I have sometimes had to also store `document.referrer` in a cookie and compare that to current `document.referrer`, in addition to `location.href`. This is because sometimes just checking if `document.referrer` is empty is not enough - there may actually be a referrer, depending on how the program/site is showing the user a preview/thumbnail.

So this will get rid of most of the extra page views..however..one major flaw with this is that it will also exclude people who legitimately come back to the site on a bookmarked page. In general this is probably unacceptable because knowing which pages give you repeat visitors is a pretty important thing.. however, it might just be the lesser of the evils; up to you to decide.